# Extracting a function in shell extension programming

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to extract some DropHandler code into a separate function, but have no idea how to do that while working with interface pointers or C++ in general. I want to get just the first item in `DragEnter` using a separate function.

```
HRESULT drop_handler::GetFirstItem(IDataObject* p_data_obj, IShellItemArray* items, IShellItem* first_item)
{
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject(p_data_obj, IID_PPV_ARGS(&items));
    if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    DWORD item_count;
    items->GetCount(&item_count);
    if (item_count != 1)
    {
        items->Release();
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    hr = items->GetItemAt(0, &first_item);
    if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        items->Release();
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

HRESULT drop_handler::DragEnter(IDataObject* p_data_obj, DWORD gtf_key_state, POINTL pt, DWORD* pdw_effect)
{
    IShellItemArray* items = nullptr;
    IShellItem* dragged_item = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = GetFirstItem(p_data_obj, items, dragged_item);
    if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    //...use dragged_item
```

This code attempt crashes Explorer big time. I'm not sure what kind of function signature and pointers I should be using to make it work.

**Edit**: Fixed answer per Anders

```
HRESULT drop_handler::GetFirstItem(IDataObject* p_data_obj, IShellItemArray*& items, IShellItem*& first_item)
{
    HRESULT hr = SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject(p_data_obj, IID_PPV_ARGS(&items));
    if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    DWORD item_count;
    hr = items->GetCount(&item_count);
    if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS || item_count != 1)
    {
        items->Release();
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    hr = items->GetItemAt(0, &first_item);
    if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        items->Release();
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}

HRESULT drop_handler::DragEnter(IDataObject* p_data_obj, DWORD gtf_key_state, POINTL pt, DWORD* pdw_effect)
{
    IShellItemArray* items;
    IShellItem* dragged_item;
    HRESULT hr = GetFirstItem(p_data_obj, items, dragged_item);
    if (hr != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    //...use dragged_item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling of `IShellItemArray*` and `IShellItem*` is wrong. `GetFirstItem` will free  `IShellItemArray*` on failure but on success you will leak it and `first_item` will never be returned correctly. `items` and `first_item` in `DragEnter` will never be valid.

`IShellItemArray*` should probably be a local variable in `GetFirstItem`.

The `IShellItem* first_item` parameter needs to be `IShellItem** first_item` or `IShellItem*& first_item` so that the pointer value is returned correctly to the caller.

You never check the return value of `GetCount`.

Since you are having problems with pointers you might want to add some `assert`s to verify that your interface pointers are non-null before using them.

Comment: Thank you! Using `IShellItem*&` in argument it compiles and works great! The reason I need to bring `IShellItemArray*` from outside is so I can release it later.